# I am just wondering why jQuery and jQuery mobile does this (not a syntax error)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On top of every jQuery Mobile page the following is included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Why does jQuery Mobile tell the page to download those three files everytime?  Instead of saving those js and css files internally within the app? They are quite big altogether.  They are maybe 500KB combined.

That can be data consuming for the ones among us who pay for the data and is not environment friendly

Or is it going to be cached in the program once it downloads those three files?

Comment: Those resources has the cache headers set... so if use it in an environment(like a browser) which respects the cache headers then these items will not be downloaded everytime

Comment: how else would page know what resources to use?

Comment: I am using jQuery mobile to build hybrid mobile application and I can choose to include those three files inside my mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers cache content making subsequent requests nearly instant.  The 3 files are the Style Sheet (CSS file), jQuery (the only dependency), and the jQuery Mobile framework (makes each page behave optimally for mobile devices)